# drupal conditional stylesheet problem!

Tags: css, drupal-6, themes

hi
i'm trying to create a new drupal theme which has many different pages and many diffrent style pages and many css files.
The template is for a specific website with specific modules and ofcourse each module has it own template
i am developing my theme under zen.
in template .info i had defined manay css files and my problem is: 
I WANT DRUPAL LOAD EACH .CSS FILE UNDER A SPECIFIC MODULE 
drupal has conditional stylesheet just for oher browsers[like IE6 IE7 , ...] but nothing for load in a specific module

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own rules in template.php file of your theme.
I'm often use this trick not for different modules, but for different paths.

```
    if ($vars['is_front']) {
    $vars['template_files'] = array();
    if (file_exists(path_to_theme().'/page-front.tpl.php')){
        $vars['template_files'][] = 'page-front';
    }
    if (file_exists(path_to_theme().'/style-front-ie6.css')) {
        $vars['ie6_style'] .= "\n".'<link type="text/css" href="/'.path_to_theme().'/style-front-ie6.css" rel="stylesheet" />';
    }
    if (file_exists(path_to_theme().'/style-front-ie7.css')) {
        $vars['ie7_style'] .= "\n".'<link type="text/css" href="/'.path_to_theme().'/style-front-ie7.css" rel="stylesheet" />';
    }
    if (file_exists(path_to_theme().'/style-front-ie8.css')) {
        $vars['ie8_style'] .= "\n".'<link type="text/css" href="/'.path_to_theme().'/style-front-ie8.css" rel="stylesheet" />';
    }
    if (file_exists(path_to_theme().'/style-front.css')) {
        drupal_add_css(path_to_theme().'/style-front.css', 'theme', 'all', FALSE);
    }
} else {
    if (module_exists('path')) {
        $alias = drupal_get_path_alias(str_replace('/edit','',$_GET['q']));
        if ($alias != $_GET['q']) {
            $template_filename = 'page';
            foreach (explode('/', $alias) as $path_part) {
                $template_filename .= '-'.$path_part;
                $vars['template_files'][] = $template_filename;
                if (file_exists(path_to_theme().'/style-'.$path_part.'-ie6.css')) {
                    $vars['ie6_style'] .= "\n".'<link type="text/css" href="/'.path_to_theme().'/style-'.$path_part.'-ie6.css" rel="stylesheet" />';
                }
                if (file_exists(path_to_theme().'/style-'.$path_part.'-ie7.css')) {
                    $vars['ie7_style'] .= "\n".'<link type="text/css" href="/'.path_to_theme().'/style-'.$path_part.'-ie7.css" rel="stylesheet" />';
                }
                if (file_exists(path_to_theme().'/style-'.$path_part.'-ie8.css')) {
                    $vars['ie8_style'] .= "\n".'<link type="text/css" href="/'.path_to_theme().'/style-'.$path_part.'-ie8.css" rel="stylesheet" />';
                }
                if (file_exists(path_to_theme().'/style-'.$path_part.'.css')) {
                    drupal_add_css(path_to_theme().'/style-'.$path_part.'.css', 'theme', 'all', FALSE);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
$css = drupal_add_css();
$vars['css'] = $css;
$vars['styles'] = drupal_get_css($css);
```

Put this into template.php in phptemplate_preprocess_page function and now if you have a page with address http://example.com/catalog, you can use page-catalog.tpl.php and style-catalog.css for it.